# Is it necessary for the random variables to be defined on the same sample space to calculate joint distribution function?

Tags: probability, distributions, kolmogorov-axioms

Is it necessary for the random variables say X and Y to be defined on the same sample space to calculate their joint distribution function?  I do not think so though I read it that way in a book.

Comment: Can you quote what you read?

Comment: What I read is not directly relevant to this context but he was referring to the condition that both X and Y are functions over the sample space.  Then I got the doubt if everywhere we deal with the RVs they should be over the same sample space.  I do not think they need be over the sample space.

Comment: It would be interesting to see how you go about working with pairs of random variables defined on different spaces *when you want to model some dependency between them:* could you tell us how you do that?